# Rename user account on Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I need to rename a user account on Windows 7 Home Premium.

If I go into the User Accounts control panel applet and choose **Change your account name**, Windows changes the account's *Display Name*.  I want to change the actual user name.  How can I do this?

I've looked at the `net user` command but it doesn't seem to be able to do this.  On Windows Pro I could use `lusrmgr.msc` but that's not available on Windows Home edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Run the command `control userpasswords2` to open the User Accounts dialog
2. Select the user account to rename and click **Properties**
3. Enter the desired username in the *User name* field and click **OK**
4. Log out and back in if changing the account currently in use

Note: This does NOT rename the account's user profile folder.